# kafka-connect error: cannot find or load main class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am following the [official docs to implement](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_kafkaconnect.%20%0A) the `kakf-connect` to read data from a file.

I have kafka running perfectly. A producer and consumer sending and receiving messages.

However, when I run the following command:

```
sudo ./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone

I crossed checked and I have the file **ConnectStandalone** here `connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/cli/ConnectStandalone`.

My `connect-file-source.properties` is as follows:

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
file=test.txt
topic=spark-kafka
```

Is there something missing? What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: can you check whether the class path is set correctly?

Comment: @Jango Could you elaborate please? How to check that?

Comment: connect/runtime/src/main/java/ this should be the class path while executing so that package org can be found and the class can be loaded. I hope this is the reason behind the failure.

Comment: @Jango I ran `export CLASSPATH=~/pathTo/connect/runtime/src/main/java/` and tried again but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

So being fairly java ignorant I think that the problem is that kafka-connect isn't included in the tarballs that kafka provides.

I instead switched to using the confluent platform, and connect works great using that tarball:

http://www.confluent.io/developer#download

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not really a solution for me because I need to use the native apache kafka for many reasons. I need a workaround for this version only. Kafka connect is already included in the tarball of kafka.